# Jquery onclick close button, hide entire span including close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css image that has a close button attached to it. I'd like to click the close button, and have the entire span fade out with jquery. This is basically my html:

```
<span class="topic_new_button">
  <a href="" class="closebutton"></a>
  <a href="" class="imglink""></a>
</span>
```

And I tried:

```
$(".closebutton").on("click", function(event) {
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.animate({ opacity: 0.05}, function() {
        $row.find(".imglink").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

But that doesn't work, can someone point out the error of my ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fadeout the entire `span`, call fadeOut() on the clicked element's parent

```
$(".closebutton").on("click", function (event) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, trying this, and not getting it to work, even though there's no reason I can see why this wouldn't work. Is there a way to call for the parent specifically being a span?

Comment: I think this is not working because your href space is blank (href="") use # here

Comment: @StevenEllenStarar you need to prevent the default action

Comment: @StevenEllenStarar so what is the problem, is it for '#' ?

Comment: I think Ijust didn't embed the jquery code quite right, my version was up-to-date, I just had too many }); after the embed, I think!

Answer (score 0):

If this and the above example do not work, your jQuery may be out of date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.closebutton').click(function() { 
    $('span').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Also, there is a mistake in your HTML code (extra quote mark), and when you have link with no reference, it returns an error, use something else as a button.

Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j01p5ryr/) using a `<button>` tag instead.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, got this working too, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

first thing you used `fadeIn` which used for showing instead use `fadeOut` or `hide`

if you are not using anymore `<span class="topic_new_button">` then below will workout

```
$(".closebutton").on("click", function (event) {
    $("#topic_new_button").fadeOut();
});
```

OR

```
$(".closebutton").on("click", function (event) {
    $("#topic_new_button").hide();
});
```